# open outlook using php on client machine

Tags: php, outlook, com

I want to open outlook using php on client machine.
I have already PHP code to open outlook window.

**Current scenario:**
I can open outlook using PHP on local server(local machine).
say localhost url : http://localhost/openOutlook/index.php
It opens the outlook on which system/server where the code is available.
It means I have code in my local system.By running that code I can open outlook perfectly.

I am using XAMPP. PHP 7.1. Windows 10. Office 2013. (in my local system)
XAMPP, PHP 7.1, server 2008 R2 (on server)
Default mail client : outlook

But when I upload the same code on Windows server 2008 R2, **IT OPENS outlook on that server it self**.
It means, URL: http://serverName/openOutlook/index.php. If I access this link from any system than Ii opens the outlook on the server itself only.
**Ideally It should open outlook in client's system.**

I checked: it is not a problem of permissions on server or so.

**What I want :**
I want to open outlook using PHP on client machine who is accessing that link.
(http:serverName/openOutlook/index.php)

Note :
I have enabled: extension=php_com_dotnet.dll

I have referred many links and questions for solution. But unfortunately nothing helped me.

This is my simple code:

```
<?php
    com_load_typelib('Outlook.Application');
    $objApp = new COM("Outlook.Application") or die ( "Cannot Load Outlook.Application" ); 

    $namespace = $objApp->GetNamespace("MAPI");  // or MAPI.Session
    $namespace->Logon(); 
    $myItem = $objApp->CreateItem ( olMailItem );   
    $myItem->To = $div_wise_value['emails'];
    $myItem->Subject = "Mail subject"; 
    $myItem->HTMLBody = "mail body";
    $myItem->Display();
?>
```

Is it possible to open outlook on any system from which the link is accessed ?
If this isn't possible, than what other approach I can use ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: i used this also: <a href="mailto:name@gmail.com">Click here to mail</a> . But it does not provide facility to pass HTML tags or contents as an email body. Only simple text is allowed in email body. Also I have to apply many setTimeout for opening multiple outlook windows.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible (at least, not in the way you'd like). Your PHP code, which runs on your server, can access COM objects on your server. You're trying to access a COM object on the client.

Theoretically, you could get information about the connecting machine's IP address, using remote COM to call functions on that machine, but almost every firewall would attempt to block that (with good reason - you're attempting to remote control the machine).

You're much better off trying to do this via HTML or javascript - there's an example here that works for some email clients:
http://resources.elixiter.com/how-to/how-to-pre-populate-the-subject-line-and-body-in-mailto-generated-emails

If you REALLY want to of this (open Outlook on the client), ActiveX is designed to do this kind of thing. But, honestly, this isn't a good idea. Even if you could do this, what happens if the person doesn't have outlook installed, for example? What if they're not on Windows? HTML and JavaScript solutions will work on more systems.

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on the server. To run your code on the client, you are pretty much limited to JS in IE, and only if you are on the trusted list and hence are allowed to create COM objects.

Create an EML file on the server (with HTML and all) and let the user download it. Outlook on the client side will be happy to open and display it. Don't forget to set the `X-Unsent:1` MIME header to make sure it is displayed as unsent by Outlook.